# Argument not specified for parameter 'FalsePart' of 'Public Function

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm trying to get a field condition to give me N/A when blank. Also to give me Fail on certain conditions. In addition, on a variable,pass/fail give me PASS or fail per the variable.
What is missing from my syntax?

```
=IIf(IsNothing(Variables!PassFail.Value),"N/A", iif(Variables!NameVer.Value = " x") Or (Variables!levPassFail.Value = "FAIL") Or (Variables!countPassFail.Value = "FAIL"),"FAIL", Variables!PassFail.Value)
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax was wrong but it's difficult to know exactly what you want to achieve.

The following will reproduce your original attempt

```
=IIF(
        IsNothing(Variables!PassFail.Value)
        ,"N/A"
        , IIF(Variables!NameVer.Value = " x" Or Variables!levPassFail.Value = "FAIL" Or Variables!countPassFail.Value = "FAIL"
                ,"FAIL"
                , Variables!PassFail.Value
                )
    )
```

**Note:** I'm not sure if  `= " x"` is a typo  and should be `= "x"` but I left your original code in there.

If this does not help, please list the possible scenarios and the required output in each, then I can offer a more accurate solution.

Comment: thank you for the reply Alan. I"m still getting BC30455] Argument not specified for parameter 'FalsePart' of 'Public Function IIf(Expression As Boolean, TruePart As Object, FalsePart As Object) As Object'.   After loading the expression and and attempting to save.     The table reference in SSRS, is a Summary table. All this table is doing is looking at outputs of variables established. Should I be using Field references instead, would this even change the symptom?

Comment: It sounds like you've missed some of the code out. I've just looked at it again and it appears to be OK, but it's midnight here so I might be tired and overlooking something... You probably need to show what you are working with. You can only use `Fields!` references to reference data in your dataset, if you are testing variables then you will have to use `Variables!`. It's just not clear what you are really trying to do.

Comment: Currently, i'm not getting any errors after saving. But i'm testing the report using report builder with random information to simulate blank or no data to give me the N/A portion of the If statement. I presume the variable itself would have to give me blank as well in order for the summary to give me the response based on blank,

Comment: "This is the variable for PassFail.value"     =IIf(Max(Fields!res.Value, "Data") > Variables!resLimitVariable.Value, "FAIL", "PASS")

Comment: You might want to either, test the `IsNothing(Variables!PassFail.Value)` part or, initialise the variable to something you can test like an empty string. I'm not sure if a variable will ever be `nothing`, I could be wrong, I just don't know so might be worth testing this part and then working on the next part once you know this part works as expected.